# Django: String object prints out None

Tags: python, django, string, view

Hello I have a view that deletes order numbers. Once a string has been deleted, the web page redirects to the clients page letting the user know that the order number was deleted. There is a problem. I am getting this.

`Previous order None deleted`

It says `None` but I want it to state the order number that I have deleted. It seems it says none because I have already deleted that order number so when it looks in the order number list, it cannot find that number.

EDIT: here is the solution. Order number should be deleted after the message is sent.

```
   def delete_confirmation(request, order_no = 0, service_type = 0):
        order = None
        count = 0
        title = models.SERVICE_CHOICES[int(service_type) - 1][1]
        #title = type[1]
        order_number = request.session['order_number']
        try:
            order = models.Order.objects.get(pk = order_no)
            count = order.orderservicelist_set.count()
            if request.POST.get('delete'):
                request.user.message_set.create(message = "Previous order " + str(order_number.pk) + "  deleted")
                order_number.delete()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(return_clients))

        except:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(return_clients))
        return render_to_response('delete_order.html', {'order':order, 'title':title, 'count':count, 'order_no':order_no }, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: maybe u can save the id of the record just before delete. then display the id in your string if the delete was successful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very Careless mistake. why have I got `order_number.delete()` written twice?

```
if request.POST.get('delete'):
    order_number.delete() # Why was this there? of course, if I have this it will delete till it gets to the next part where it informs the user which order number was deleted! 
    request.user.message_set.create(message = "Previous order " + str(order_number.pk) + "  deleted")
    order_number.delete()
```

fixed

Comment: Don't put this as an answer, just edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things that `delete()` does on a model instance is set its pk to `None`, so that if you try and save it, it will create a new instance rather than trying to update the old (no-longer-existing) one.

So, easy solution: grab the PK before you delete. In fact, you could just get rid of the first call to `delete` you have there, because you call it again after creating the message.

By the way, a better way of creating the message is to use string formatting:

```
message = "Previous order %s deleted" % order_number.pk
```